# Consuming OffsetDateTime in Jersey

Tags: java, date, jersey, jax-rs, datetimeoffset

I'm trying to make my server parse the following JSON:

```json
{"hardwareId":1,"registerTime":"2017-02-14T03:42:11.482Z","sensorId":1,"temperature":23.6}
```

The `registerTime` property must be parsed into an `OffsetDateTime` instance:

```java
@XmlRootElement
public class TemperatureRegister {

    private int m_hardwareId;
    private int m_sensorId;
    private OffsetDateTime m_registerTime;
    private double m_temperature;

    public TemperatureRegister() {

    }

    public TemperatureRegister(OffsetDateTime p_registerTime, double p_temperature, 
                               int p_hardwareId, int p_sensorId) {

        if (p_registerTime == null) {
            this.m_registerTime = OffsetDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC);
        }
        this.m_registerTime = p_registerTime;
        this.m_temperature = p_temperature;
        this.m_hardwareId = p_hardwareId;
        this.m_sensorId = p_sensorId;
    }

    ...
 }
```

That's how my resource method is defined:

```java
@POST
@Path("/insert")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public TemperatureRegister addOne(TemperatureRegister p_register) {
    m_mongoConnector.InsertOne(p_register);
    return p_register;
}
```

For some reason, in the method above, the `p_register` parameter is always like this:

```
TemperatureRegister [m_hardwareId=1, m_sensorId=1, m_registerTime=null, m_temperature=23.6]
```

It maps everything correctly BUT the `registerTime` which is `OffsetDateTime`. It'ss always `null`. Why is this the only problematic value?

Am I doing something wrong? Does it need some special configuration to handle OffsetDateTime`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Jackson as JSON provider, you need the [`jackson-datatype-jsr310`](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-modules-java8) dependency to support [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html):

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.6</version>
</dependency>
```

You also want to annotate the `TemperatureRegister` fields with [`@JsonProperty`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonProperty.html) when your class field names don't match the JSON property names:

```java
public class TemperatureRegister {

    @JsonProperty("hardwareId")
    private int m_hardwareId;

    @JsonProperty("sensorId")
    private int m_sensorId;

    @JsonProperty("registerTime")
    private OffsetDateTime m_registerTime;

    @JsonProperty("temperature")
    private double m_temperature;

    // Constructor, getters and setters omitted
}
```

Comment: @filscapo If my answer solved your issue, please consider accepting it by clicking the green tick next to my answer :)

Comment: OH!!  tks for remembering me =]